# 今このしゅんかん - に私が生きている in full cursive?

Tags: hiragana, handwriting, calligraphy

Can I ask you if you know how to write this sentences in full cursive?

1. 抱えて生きている
2. 今このしゅんかん - に私が生きている

Yes, unfortunately the second one has to be broken, that means that it has to be written in two different columns (I don't think it is correct, but it's for a friend of mine and it has to be like that :/ ).

I need it in full cursive because I need something like this:

[image]

[image]

I have also a personal question: does it make sense to write hiragana in full cursive? I mean, is it normal?

Comment: 「抱えて生きている」ってどういう意味？

Comment: I found it here (https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/5814/does-the-expression-%E6%8A%B1%E3%81%88%E3%81%A6%E7%94%9F%E3%81%8D%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%82%8B-always-imply-a-situation-with-negative-aspects) I can't create links :(